# Azure Search - 503 Unavailable Alert

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to understand how to detect **503 - Service Unavailable** errors from Azure Search **via Azure Monitor**.

Sometimes one of our instances is not scaled enough to handle indexing jobs, but it is hard to tell on the application side (we only get a 503 when calling the service directly) and I could not find any metric on Azure Monitor. On the other hand, going to the portal directly, on the "Indexers" tab, we notice many of them failing with the aforementioned exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not find any metric on Azure Monitor.

It seems that no such feature on Azure Search.

You could refer to the issue as below and vote up it to promote it to achieve. 
[Azure Search Alerts](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10095111-azure-search-alerts)